# How to implement RBAC in azure and flask application

Tags: python, azure, flask, azure-rbac

I want to implement Azure RBAC in a flask application. How should I do it?

Inside the web app, Users can assign and remove roles to other users.

Comment: Can you share the code you have tried so far? @Nitin Raturi

Answer (score 0):

> How to implement RBAC in azure and flask application: -

To achieve your requirement, firstly install [`pip install Flask-OAuthlib`](https://pypi.org/project/Flask-OAuthlib/) package as it is used for flask app authorization with `Oauth`(Azure RBAC).

`pip install Flask-OAuthlib`

[image]

Now when it comes to implementation of RBAC in a flask app, follow below detailed steps.

1. Register a new app under Azure AD B2C and provide a flask web app URL in Redirect URL field. Once you registered it, create a client secret and store it with you.
   [image]
2. Now go to `API permissions` and add the required Graph API permissions according to the requirement.
3. In order to use Azure AD B2C in a flask app, the main thing you need to use is [`oauth.remote_app`](https://python.hotexamples.com/examples/flask_oauthlib.client/OAuth/remote_app/python-oauth-remote_app-method-examples.html) function in the python code which is given below.

```py
from flask import Flask, redirect, url_for, session
from flask_oauthlib.client import OAuth
app = Flask(__name__)
app.secret_key = 'secretxxxx'
oauth = OAuth(app)

azure = oauth.remote_app(
    'azure',
    consumer_key='client_id',
    consumer_secret='client_secret',
    request_token_params={'scope': 'openid email profile'},
    base_url='https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/',
    request_token_url=None,
    access_token_method='POST',
    access_token_url='https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenantID}/oauth2/v2.0/token',
    authorize_url='https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenantID}/oauth2/v2.0/authorize'
)

@app.route('/')
def index():
    return 'Azure RBAC Flask App is running'

@app.route('/login')
def login():
    return azure.authorize_redirect(redirect_uri=url_for('authorized', _external=True))

@app.route('/logout')
def logout():
    session.pop('azuretoken', None)
    return 'Logged out'

@app.route('/login/authorized')
def authorized():
    response = azure.authorized_response()
    if response is None or response.get('access_token') is None:
        return 'Access denied: reason={} error={}'.format(
            request.args['error_reason'],
            request.args['error_description']
        )
    session['azuretoken'] = response
    return 'Logged in'
```

```py
python -m flask run --host localhost --port 5000
```

*Output*:

[image]

*References*:

[Adding auth to a Flask App with Azure Active Directory and Oso](https://www.osohq.com/post/oso-azure) for more relevant information.

[Configuring authentication in a python app](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/configure-authentication-sample-python-web-app?tabs=windows) using Azure RBAC. And same will be applicable for flask web app as well.